# How to fix: "cannot import name: OneCycleLR"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, importerror

I am working on a classification problem following a tutorial. I am working on TensorFlow and Keras 2 on Python 3 with CUDA 9.0. When I execute the following command on Jupyter notebook:

```
from clr import OneCycleLR
```

It gives me the following error

```
    ImportError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-5cf3ef13bfbe> in <module>()
  7 from segmentation_models.metrics import iou_score
  8 from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
----> 9 from clr import OneCycleLR

ImportError: cannot import name 'OneCycleLR'
```

Please let me know how I can solve this.